# How to add text to speech on recognition of any object in tensorflow object detection apllication>

Tags: android, text-to-speech, tensorflow-lite

I am designing an app that will helps the blind users detect hurdles in their way. For this purpose, i need the application to speak that the object or hurdle is detected whenever any object is detected.

I have already tried adding Text-to-speech in it but is does not says that the object is detected.

```
// Find the best classifications.
PriorityQueue<Recognition> pq =
    new PriorityQueue<Recognition>(
        3,
        new Comparator<Recognition>() {
          @Override
          public int compare(Recognition lhs, Recognition rhs) {
            // Intentionally reversed to put high confidence at the head of the queue.
            return Float.compare(rhs.getConfidence(), lhs.getConfidence());
          }
        });
for (int i = 0; i < outputs.length; ++i) {
  if (outputs[i] > THRESHOLD) {
    pq.add(
        new Recognition(
            "" + i, labels.size() > i ? labels.get(i) : "unknown", outputs[i], null));
  }
}

    mTtsSpeaker = new TtsSpeaker();
    //mTtsSpeaker.setHasSenseOfHumor(true);
    mTtsEngine = new TextToSpeech(TensorFlowImageClassifier.this,
            new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
              @Override
              public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                  mTtsEngine.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                  //mTtsEngine.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(utteranceListener);
                  mTtsSpeaker.speakReady(mTtsEngine);
                } else {
                  Log.w(TAG, "Could not open TTS Engine (onInit status=" + status
                          + "). Ignoring text to speech");
                  mTtsEngine = null;
                }
              }
            });





final ArrayList<Recognition> recognitions = new ArrayList<Recognition>();
int recognitionsSize = Math.min(pq.size(), MAX_RESULTS);
for (int i = 0; i < recognitionsSize; ++i) {
  recognitions.add(pq.poll());

}
if (mTtsEngine != null) {
  // speak out loud the result of the image recognition
  mTtsSpeaker.speakResults(mTtsEngine, recognitions);
}
Trace.endSection(); // "recognizeImage"
return recognitions;


  }
```

Comment: why don't you put a log statement ' Log.i(TAG, "yes, this code was reached"); ' directly above the line ' mTtsSpeaker.speakResults(mTtsEngine, recognitions); '  Then you'll know if that line is even being executed or not.  If not, then just trace the code backwards and do more Log statements until you find the problem.

Comment: Thanks i resolved it a few days ago.

Comment: @Iqratoheed can you update the question with the solution ?